# find method can't accept params[:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
def admission2
  puts params[:id]
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @guardian = Guardian.new params[:guardian]
  if request.post? and @guardian.save
    redirect_to :controller => "student", :action => "admission2", :id => @student.id
  end
end
```

In given code, find method throws an exception saying that

```
  Couldn't find Student without an ID
```

but the output of `puts` statement shows that `params[:id]` contains a value. I've made sure that the record for given `id` field always exist in database.

When I manually put a number as `find` methods parameter, it worked so I guess find is unable accept `params[:id]` here, is there any other way of doing it?

I'm using rails 2.3.5

Comment: Can you show your model? Did you perhaps override the find method?

Comment: The whole stack trace would help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my old routes.rb file:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id/:id2'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

I just removed `map.connect ':controller/:action'` from it and now everything is working perfetctly.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty odd. Does it make any difference if you do

```
@student = Student.find params[:id].to_i
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.Maybe something is wrong with my environment.